# Counting Group of order n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I know how to count number of non isomorphic group in case of abelian case by Fundamental theorem of abelian case .
I am interested in how to count non abelian non isomorphic group. I don't know is it possible or not?

But many examples (of small order ) are asked in exercise to find that. I am using observation about possible non abelian group. Many time some group remain to be un counted.

For example: Group of order $8$. So there $3$ abelian group $Z_8$,$Z_4\times Z_2$,$Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_2$, and Non abelian group of $D_4 $ and $ Q_8$.

How to guarantee that our listing is complete or some group had to be mention?

Comment: The general problem (with any order) is difficult: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups

Comment: Can you precise your question? Are you expecting a close formula $d_n$ for the number of non abelian non isomorphic groups of order $n$? An algorithm to find all non isomorphic non Abel Ian groups of order $n$?

Comment: The smallest $n$, for which the number of groups of order $n$ upto isomorphy (often called $gnu(n)$) is unknown, is $n=2^{11}=2048$

Comment: Alexander Konovalov posted a very good survey of many values on github which are mostly doublechecked.

Comment: @Peter That’s not « a huge number »....

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sir I wanted to find if possible formula or algorithm to find number of non isomorphic non abelian possible .Is it possible to count ?

Comment: If you look at the problem from a theoretical standpoint an algorithm isn’t so difficult to devise. Take $I_n=\{1,\dots, n\}$, take all operations on it and verify that equipped as such it is a group. From there, you can look at the groups that are non abelian. And then find the one that are not isomorphic... Now, this algorithm will be very inefficient !